# Python: Automatically updating Twitch moderator list using API

Tags: python, api, dictionary, twitch

I'm trying to auto update a moderator list using this API:
https://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/ice3lade/chatters

I am accessing and storing it with

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
response = urlopen('https://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/ice3lade/chatters')
chatlist = response.read()
```

But attempting to simply use it as a dictionary e.g.

```
print(chatlist("chatters"))
```

Returns an error

```
TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable
```

I'm a total python noob so any help is appreciated. How do I either access this as a dictionary directly from the API, or how to store the data I get from reading the API as a proper dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Made a fairly reasonable solution, chatlist gives the full dictionary, chatters gives all the keys and values within the chatters dictionary, and moderators gives the list of moderators.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from json import loads
response = urlopen('https://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/xflixx_teampokerstars/chatters')
readable = response.read().decode('utf-8')
chatlist = loads(readable)
chatters = chatlist['chatters']
moderators = chatters['moderators']
```

Didn't know json was required to decode the API.